# AWK print regex pattern

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I am trying to print a regex pattern for the following piece of mail log. In particular I am trying to get the ID between the square brackets (see the second line for reference).

```
Mar 29 03:48:13 mx-150 clamsmtpd: 14114F: accepted connection from: 127.0.0.1
Mar 29 03:48:13 mx-150 postfix/smtpd[7445]: connect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
Mar 29 03:48:13 mx-150 spamd[15674]: prefork: child states: II
```

and using the following command:

```
awk '/\[\d+\]/ { print }' maillog
```

According to https://regex101.com/r/pL7kN2/1 I am getting 1 match, however, awk is not returning anything. Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try standard regexps (instead of `perl` regexps). This will print matching lines:

```
awk '/\[[[:digit:]]+\]/ { print }' maillog
```

To extract and print the matching value inside the brackets:

```
awk 'match($0,/\[[[:digit:]]+\]/) { print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}' maillog
```

Comment: Hi Janis, seems I am getting hits using what you have pasted. Is there any place I can verify my regex online not being afraid that it is not going to be compatibile with awk?

Comment: I know there are regexp test pages on the Web, so a search will very likely make you find something. Search for BRE (basic regular expressions) or ERE (extended regular expressions). Those regexps are standard on Unix. (Syntax differences in different applications will only be whether and how regexp meta-characters are escaped or not.) I think the syntax of the regexps that are supported by [GNU] awk are also described in the GNU awk manual.

Comment: FWIW in `mawk` it appears not to work with POSIX class `[[:digit:]]` but **does** work with range `[0-9]` (at least on my Ubuntu box: mawk 1.3.3). See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mawk/+bug/69724

Answer (score 3):

Another approach:

```
awk -F'[][]' 'NR>1{print $2}' maillog
7445
15674
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like `awk` next script prints every second field if string divided by `[]` (that's mean inside of it)

```
awk -F [][] '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)print $i}' maillog
```

But do the same by `grep` much simple

```
grep -o '\[[^]]*\]' maillog
```

Comment: Your first command will not work with csh, tcsh, zsh, bash -O failglob or if there's a file called `[` or `]` in the current directory.

Comment: Cheers for your help, I am trying to learn awk even though I am tempted to use grep and other useful commands :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you wish to match

```
awk -F"[][]" '/postfix|spamd/{print $2}' maillog
```